# parse JSON in jquery Autocomplete

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-autocomplete

On key entry in autocomplete box, I am returning Key,Value pair from MVC controller in JSON format.

```
public ActionResult UserNameAutoComplete(string term)
{
    DBEntities db = new DBEntities();

    ...codes to get data from database 

    jsonString += jSearializer.Serialize(userList);
    return Json(jsonString, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

the retruned Json String is [{"UserId":"1","UserName":"admin"},{"UserId":"3","UserName":"newtonsheikh"}]

In the View i am getting this

[image]

The jquery is

```
$("#Username").autocomplete({
    source: '@Url.Action("UserNameAutoComplete")'
});
```

My question is how do i parse this returned json? The expected output is
[image]

Comment: System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer jSearializer =
                   new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

object of this class

Answer (score 6):

solved the issue. i had to change my jquery code. There is no need to change the code for returning the json string.

```
$("#Username").autocomplete({
        select: function (e, ui) {
            $("#Username").val(ui.item.label);
            return false;
        },

        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("UserNameAutoComplete")',
                data: request,
                success: function (data) {
                    var ParsedObject = $.parseJSON(data);
                    response($.map(ParsedObject, function (item) {
                        return {
                            label: item.UserName,
                            value: item.UserId
                        };

                    }))
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You trying to serialize your dataSet twice. 
You need use

```
return Json(jsonString, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

without(!) jSerializer.

or if you want do this with serializer try return just content of your serialized dataset

```
jsonString += jSearializer.Serialize(userList);
return Content(jsonString);
```